# hibernate not updating a persistant object from a transactional method

Tags: hibernate

I have a object of class person in DB `{id=1, name="a"}`
I create a new instance of that object `Person p = new Person(1,"b")`.
Then I do `getSession().saveOrUpdate(p)`

I expected that hibernate will update name from "a" to "b" but its not doing that.
I have put this code inside a Transactional method.

Comment: The problem is at line 231. That's what my crystal ball says.

Comment: No, I thought its in line no 235 @JBNizet.

Comment: What @JBNizet is hinting (oh so subtly), is that we can't help you without you posting (at least) the DAO and service methods you are using, as well as a snippet of the object you are trying to save (showing the fields that object has), at a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load existing data from database as follows,

```
Person p = session.load(Person.class, 1);
p.setName("b");
session.update(p);
transaction.commit();
session.clear();
session.close();
```

Comment: Any idea why my code is neither throwing exception nor its updating the data

Comment: Hibernate session will update object only on objects attached in session. The reason behind loading an object using session is for attachment purpose.